# jQuery ajax function not working in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i am using jquery ajax in laravel for reading some data from database. i wrote this code and the $ajax() part not working! but every thing before that working great. what is wrong ?

```
$('#file_type').on('change',function(){
        $value=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url : '{{URL::to('fileType.categories')}}',
            data:{'file_type':$value},
            success:function(data){
                alert('ooooops1');
                $('#file_type_cats').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
```

my routes are OK. i'm using select element to run ajax. if i write alert($value); before $.ajax() it works good. but ajax not working.

> update: solved
>   i was using the route name which is wrong. i must use the url intself not the name!.

Comment: does any error appears in the console ?

Comment: no. nothig appears at all!

Comment: Have you debugged? Are you sure for instance that a request is not being sent?

Comment: this is the console log:
ReferenceError: errorMessage is not defined[Learn More] create:207:13
<anonymous>
http://localhost/pikland/public/picture/create:207:13
dispatch
http://localhost/pikland/public/js/jquery.min.js:3:10264
add/q.handle
http://localhost/pikland/public/js/jquery.min.js:3:8326
receiveMessage
resource://gre/actors/SelectChild.jsm:292:13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the route helper if you want to use the route name:

```
{{ route('fileType.categories') }}
```